# SublimeText 2 web.config xml formatting

Tags: sublimetext2

I have moved 90% of my development IDE work to SublimeText.   The more I use it, the more I love its simplicity.

I am not able to figure out how to set code formating / coloring for different file extensions.  How can I let subllimeText know .config files are xml files?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can set this with:

1. Open your .config file
2. View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> XML

Comment: I feel dumb. I thought i had to tweak configs.   Thanks

Comment: A logical assumption, given its current state.